# Python: Hold data in memory after closing program

Tags: python, eclipse, memory, attributes

I have a several huge attributes in my code which takes about 4 mb each. When I start the application in Eclipse, the program has to load all these attributes from files. It takes about 30 seconds. Is there a way to hold these attributes in memory, so I would not have to wait for 30 seconds everytime I run the program?

I think it would be possible in C using pointers.

Thanks for advices

Comment: Do you about memcached? There is a Python implementation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached/ You would have to set up a memcache server too, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it using C pointers.   When program exists all it's allocated memory is released.  As well as other resources like open files and database connections.

What you can do is set-up some memory cache server.   You can use memcached  as John Barca suggested, personally I use  Redis http://redis.io/ for such things.

However, keep in mind that memcached and redis will only help with file reading times.  How many of 4mb attributes do you have?   On modern computer loading 4mb file should be instantaneous.  Possibly your program spends time parsing the attributes read from the file,  in such case you'd better use something like [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to save and load the objects.  You should have some logic in your program that compares the time-stamps on you pickled files and the original data files and load from appropriate source.

Comment: Thank you for advices. Yes I use pickle. For example this: `def fileReadDictionaryInMemory():
    print inspect.stack()[0][3]
    with open("dictionaryinMemory.txt",'rb') as f:
        dictionary = pickle.load(f)
    return dictionary` Takes 4.9 sec. The file takes 8 mb. This is how I save it: `with open("dictionaryInMemory.txt", 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(dictionaryMemory,f)` It is normal? My machine: Intel Core 2 Duo - 2 GHz - 3 GB

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution. There's an outer process that holds onto the expensive resource and imports a module that can use the resource. The module code can be changed and then reloaded while the outer process continues running and continues holding onto the expensive resource.

main.py

```
# importlib for python 3, not needed for 2
#import importlib
expensive_data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# need to import successfully before using importlib.reload()
import usedata
while(True):
    raw_input("waiting")
    # use this for python 3
    #importlib.reload(usedata)
    # and this for python 2
    reload(usedata)
    usedata.func(expensive_data)
```

usedata.py

```
def func(data):
    print [i+2 for i in data]

#def func(data):
#    print [i+3 for i in data]
```

As a test you can start main.py and switch the function that gets used in usedata.py by changing which function is commented.

Comment: Wow, I really liked the idea.